# error Command failed with exit code 1. react-three nextjs yarn

Tags: reactjs, next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

when i try to `yarn build` i am getting this error `error Command failed with exit code 1.`
it's working fine in dev no errors no nothing but whenever i try to build i get that error

code:

```
export default function GlbModelViewer(props: { url: string }) {
    // Initialize state for the size of the model and the colors of the materials
    const [modelSize, setModelSize] = useState(new Vector3(0, 0, 0))
    const [materialColors, setMaterialColor] = useState<RGB[]>([])
    
    function getBackgroundColor(materialColors: RGB[]) {
        // Calculate the average color
        let avgColor = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 }
        materialColors.forEach(color => {
            avgColor.r += color.r
            avgColor.g += color.g
            avgColor.b += color.b
        })
        avgColor.r /= materialColors.length
        avgColor.g /= materialColors.length
        avgColor.b /= materialColors.length
        
        // Calculate the brightness of the average color
        let brightness = Math.sqrt(
            0.299 * avgColor.r * avgColor.r + 0.587 * avgColor.g
            * avgColor.g + 0.114 * avgColor.b * avgColor.b
        )
        
        // Decide the background color based on the brightness
        return brightness > 0.5 ? 'black' : 'white'
    }   
    
    // Return the Canvas component with the loaded 3D model and configured scene
    return (
        <Canvas dpr={[1, 2]} className="min-w-full  min-h-full">
            <color attach="background" args={[getBackgroundColor(materialColors)]} />
            {/* @ts-ignore */}
            <ambientLight intensity={10} />
            {/* @ts-ignore */}
            <directionalLight intensity={1} />
            <CameraRig modelSize={modelSize} />
            <Center>
                <Model 
                    setMaterialsColor={setMaterialColor}
                    setModelSize={setModelSize}
                    url={props.url}
                />
            </Center>
        </Canvas>
  )
}

function Model({ url, setModelSize, setMaterialsColor }: ModelTypes) {
    const modelRef = useRef<Mesh>() // Create a ref for the 3D model
    const model = useGLTF(url) // Load the 3D model from the provided URL
    
    const allColors: RGB[] = [] // Initialize an array to store the colors of the model's materials
    // Traverse the nodes of the 3D model
    model.scene.traverse(node => {
        // Cast the node to a Mesh and its material to a MeshStandardMaterial
        const nodeMesh = node as Mesh
        const nodeMaterial = nodeMesh.material as MeshStandardMaterial
        // If the node is a mesh and its material has a color, add the color to the array
        if (nodeMesh.isMesh && nodeMaterial.color.isColor) {
            const newColor = {
                r: nodeMaterial.color.r,
                g: nodeMaterial.color.g,
                b: nodeMaterial.color.b,
            }
          allColors.push(newColor)
        }
    })
    setMaterialsColor(allColors) // Set the materials color state with the array of colors
    
    // When the component mounts or the model changes, calculate the size of the model and set the model size state
    useEffect(() => {
        const box = new Box3().setFromObject(model.scene)
        const size = new Vector3()
        box.getSize(size)
        setModelSize(size)
    }, [])
    
    // On each frame, if the model ref is defined, rotate the model around the y-axis
    useFrame(() => {
        if (modelRef.current) {
            modelRef.current.rotation.y += 0.001
        }
    })
    
    // Return a primitive component with the 3D model and a scale of 0.1
    return <primitive ref={modelRef} object={model.scene} scale={0.1} />
}

function CameraRig({ modelSize }: { modelSize: Vector3 }) {
    // Get the camera from the React Three Fiber context
    const { camera } = useThree()
    
    // Calculate the largest dimension of the model
    const largestDimension = Math.max(modelSize.x, modelSize.y, modelSize.z)
    
    // Update the camera position when the model size changes
    useEffect(() => {
        camera.position.set(0, 0, largestDimension * 1.2)
    }, [modelSize])
    
    // Return the OrbitControls component with zooming disabled and polar angle limits set
    return <OrbitControls
               enableZoom={false}
               minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 9}
               maxPolarAngle={Math.PI - Math.PI / 7}
           />
}
```

attempt 1 to fix it:
i tried to reinstall all the packages but it did not work

attempt 2 to fix it:
i started removing very component to find the component that is causing this i thought i found it and it did work but when i tried it second time it did not

attempt 3 to fix it:
i tried to import and export is dynamically i also used react Suspense but nothing worked

attempt 4 to fix it: again i tried removing components removing model and color and all the lighting work but the thing is i need those without them there is no point in build this